# Column chart issue, column's height is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem with google chart. Please refer to image below.

[image]

BMI with value 27.7 is bigger than BMI 28.3 on the left side. Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: How we can help you without source code?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Incorrect data format from mysql. should be number, was string